# More graceful deployments on AWS (NodeJS)

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, deployment, amazon-ec2

I'm running a NodeJS based app on AWS (EC2), and everything has gone quite smoothly so far. Last week however, our client noticed that when we do a deployment, the site goes down for a good minute. Looking into this a bit, this seems to be the startup time of my node application (reading all manner of config files, connecting to services, warming up cache). I have a couple of questions about this:

- Does the new "deploy" run on the same virtual machine or is the machine torn down before the new `npm start` command is run?
- Is there a way to have AWS wait for a signal before letting the new code take over?

Comment: Are you using AWS CodeDeploy?

Comment: No, we're building on Jenkins.

Comment: OK thanks. And the deployment mechanism from Jenkins to the servers is what exactly?

Comment: Run specs, Build assets, Zip up everything except node_modules and test folders, Push to S3 bucket, Deploy to EB. We're using this Jenkins plugin: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/AWSEB+Deployment+Plugin

Answer (score 1):

In AWS You can deploy a Node APP in different ways to handle more graceful deployments.

**[Using EC2, Load balancing](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/)**

In this setup you can configure at least 2 instances of EC2 with Node App and deploy the update to each instance in order (At least provision 2 instances just before the update happens using Jenkins). You have to setup the instances behind a load balancer to keeping the system available for use so that when one instance is not available due to update in progress, requests are sent by load balancer to the other instance.

**[Using AWS Elastic Beanstalk](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_nodejs.html)**

This is the recommended way to do if you are deploying existing Node App. Beanstalk platform is able to do rolling updates. You can also create a new environment in Beanstalk and do [Blue Green Deployments](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.CNAMESwap.html) swapping the DNS records.

**[Using AWS ECS](https://aws.amazon.com/ecs/details/)**

If you can containerized your Node App, then you can go for this and create a service with multiple instances running where you can do rolling. The advantage here is starting new container instances are really fast(Happens in few seconds), in comparison to starting EC2 instances(Happens in minutes).

**[Using AWS Lambda, API Gateway, Cloudfront & S3](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/running-express-applications-on-aws-lambda-and-amazon-api-gateway/)**

This is the modern way to setup Node Apps using Lambda, where the platform will handle most of the quality attributes of the system. For example deployments without downtime, availability, availability & etc. These architectures are generally called serverless architectures.